# DirectMessageListenerContainer prints stack trace when Retry Policy Exhausted

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Looking at the source code for class org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer inside of the `callExecuteListener(Message message, long deliveryTag)` method, the following happens

1. `executeListener(getChannel(), message);` is called
2. If an exception is thrown, the logger prints the following message with the stack trace `logger.error("Failed to invoke listener", e);`

I don't need the stack trace to pollute the log in situations of AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException thrown because my Retry Policy has been Exhausted, however I do want the stack traces for other exceptions.

I dont see an easy mechanism to override this behavior.
What options do I have besides turning off logging completely for DirectMessageListenerContainer  or writting a slf4j filter? Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't miss anything. We recently added this there though:

```
if (causeChainHasImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException(e)) {
                if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    this.logger.debug("User requested ack for failed delivery: " + deliveryTag);
                }
                handleAck(deliveryTag, channelLocallyTransacted);
            }
```

So, I think we could improve the logic there to skip an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` as well.

Feel free to raise a JIRA ticket on the matter. Also contribution is welcome!